# Display Product Addons in Columns (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I am using product addons in Woocommerce. Unfortunately, with the current functionality, each new addon goes after the other. Just like this:

Addon 1

Addon 2

and so on..

You can visit the link here [enter link description here](http://wonderpromo.atoz.digital)

Now, what I was trying to do is:

Whenever there's more than one add on then it should follow the following layout:

Addon 1 | Addon 2

Addon 3 | Addon 4

Addon 5

and so on..

Below is the existing code for the addons

```html
<div class="<?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo 'required-product-addon'; ?> product-addon product-addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_start', $addon ); ?>

 <?php if ( $name ) : ?>
  <h3 class="addon-name"><?php echo wptexturize( $name ); ?> <?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo '<abbr class="required" title="' . __( 'Required field', 'woocommerce-product-addons' ) . '">*</abbr>'; ?></h3>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php if ( $description ) : ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="addon-description">' . wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) ) . '</div>'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_options', $addon ); ?>
```

Please help!

Here's what I tried with my little knowledge of PHP:

```html
<div class="su-row">
<div class="su-column su-column-size-1-2"><div class="su-column-inner su-clearfix">
<div class="<?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo 'required-product-addon'; ?> product-addon product-addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_start', $addon ); ?>

 <?php if ( $name ) : ?>
  <h3 class="addon-name"><?php echo wptexturize( $name ); ?> <?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo '<abbr class="required" title="' . __( 'Required field', 'woocommerce-product-addons' ) . '">*</abbr>'; ?></h3>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php if ( $description ) : ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="addon-description">' . wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) ) . '</div>'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_options', $addon ); ?>
</div></div>
<div class="su-column su-column-size-1-2"><div class="su-column-inner su-clearfix">
<? php if (i+1 == $addon) ?>
<div class="<?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo 'required-product-addon'; ?> product-addon product-addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_start', $addon ); ?>

 <?php if ( $name ) : ?>
  <h3 class="addon-name"><?php echo wptexturize( $name ); ?> <?php if ( 1 == $required ) echo '<abbr class="required" title="' . __( 'Required field', 'woocommerce-product-addons' ) . '">*</abbr>'; ?></h3>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php if ( $description ) : ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="addon-description">' . wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) ) . '</div>'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php do_action( 'wc_product_addon_options', $addon ); ?>

</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this isn't a php related question at all, this is html/css related.

Comment: At least a little bit of PHP to specify that when there's more than one addon, so and so should be the layout.

Comment: BTW do you have the solution for this? PLEASE!

Comment: This site is not for find professionals who make your job instead of you for free. Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: I just updated the question @Peter And for sure I am not trying to be oversmart. It's just a situation for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just because this question can be answered easier in CSS doesn't mean that it should be re-branded a CSS question, especially as it is possible to answer the question with PHP!

Comment: But what's the answer?